# How to add toggleClass to a checked checkbox with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, text, checkbox, checked, toggleclass

I append some input textfields and checkboxes onclick. 
But when a checkbox is checked i want to toggleClass to the input textfield.
This is my create code:

```
jQuery(function() {
var counter = 0;

$('#appendbtn').click(function() {
    var elems = '<div>' + '<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"' + (counter) + '" class="item"/>' + '<input type="text" id="inputfield"' + (counter) + '"/>' + '</div>';
    $('#box').append(elems);
    counter++;
    return false;
});
```

This is what should happen;

```
if ($("#checkbox").is(":checked"))
 {
$("inputfield" + counter).toggleClass("complete")
 });
```

Ofcourse this isn't correct, but i hope you get what i mean ;)
is this by the way possible without an if statement?

here is the jsfiddle http://www.jsfiddle.net/gkdKY/

oh and this is exactly what i want http://www.jsfiddle.net/xzmcL/
but with appended checkboxes!

Comment: Your `elems`-string is not correct `'<input id="checkbox"' + (counter) + '"` will end up as `<input id="checkbox"1"`. The same applies to your textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
var elems = '<div>' + '<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"' + (counter) + '" class="item"/>' + '<input type="text" id="inputfield"' + (counter) + '"/>' + '</div>';
```

...has two extra quotes. It should be:

```
var elems = '<div>' + '<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox' + (counter) + '" class="item"/>' + '<input type="text" id="inputfield' + (counter) + '"/>' + '</div>';
```

That breaks your selector for the `click` event. But note, that won't work anyway, since you are trying to hook an element that does not exist until the 'click me' link is pressed - so you need to use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for that anyway.

Something like this might work:

```
$("#drag").delegate("input[type=checkbox]", "change", function(){
   var index = this.id.substring(8);
   $("#inputfield" + index).toggleClass("complete");
});
```

Comment: Thank you sje397, it doesnt seem to work may i ask why substring(8) ? :)

Comment: @Opoe: `substring(8)` converts an id like `checkbox13` to `13` by removing the first 8 characters.

Comment: @Opoe: I just made a small edit (removed '.' from start of 'complete') - oops.

Comment: No - the event that is handled is the change of the checkbox - so inside the `delegate` function, `this` refers to the checkbox, so `this.id` is `checkbox<n>` where `n` is the counter value.

Comment: Okay thank you so much for helping me. The checkboxes are appended so why isn't it .delegate("#checkbox"), "change", function (){}

Comment: @Opoe: you can't have more than one element with a particular id. When you fix the quotes as mentioned at the top of my answer, each checkbox gets a new id with a number on the end. `#checkbox` would only select the element with that particular id. And, `delegate` is (almost) always used with some kind of parent container (since it "delegates" the event handling).

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it, i don't just want the answer to copy paste! But now i get it and it works thank you so much!

Comment: @Opoe: no problem. Good to hear!

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
   $('#inputfield').toggleClass('bold');
});
```

I'm assuming you aren't setting your checkboxes' checked state to true dynamically.

Comment: thank you, yes its onclick :) it doesnt add or toggle to the class bold yet though